# Multiple Cursor in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Multiple Cursor is not working in VSCode. I tried with `Alt+Left click`. But it is not working. My VSCode settings is like below.

[image]

Comment: cannot repro. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.